# How to add multiple request in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading

I want to create `Operation` of sending images to server.
I want to control the request (`Resume`, `Pause` and `Cancel`).
`NSOperation` queue is better idea to handle the operations.

I want to add into `Background thread` and it should perform uploading request to server without interrupting the `Main thread` of App.

Can any operation complete independently and how do we achieve this scenario.

Comment: have you check afnetworking?

Comment: We don't want to use any third party library for App development.

Comment: ok let me check and copy paste the code of AFNetworking here.

Comment: please follow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134427/running-multiple-background-threads-ios?rq=1) Hope it helps

Comment: we can not control the Image uploading like resume, pause and cancel.

Comment: So I do something like this in my app without AFNetwork. You can create your own subclass of NSOperation which handles the ulpoad for you. To be sure that you can suspend the queue whenever you want you have to set a semaphore in the NSOperation. One at the start of main and one at the end of upload. If you don't do this, the Operation will be finished even if your upload is still running.